# create whare clause on model attribute

Tags: laravel, eloquent, orm, model, relation

How to create `where` clause on laravel model attribute
I have the following relation between `user` and `books`. where user `hasMany` books and the `book` model belongs to single user
I want to `select all books with pages > 100 that belongs to user_id = 2`

I use laravel 5.2 with mysql and defined a model for `User` and another model for `Book`
When I want to get all books for specific user, I user

```
return User::find(2)->books;
```

and this works fine. But I want to get the books where pages > 100. I use:

```
return User::find(2)->books->where([['pages', '>', 100], ['chapters', '>', 3]]);
```

but doesn't work

User model:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function books()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Book');
    }
}
```

Book model

```
class Book extends Model
{

  public function user()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
  }
}
```

I expect to get all the books with user_id = 0 and pages > 100 and chapters > 3

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to access the relationship method `books()`, not the property `books`. Some quotes from the documentation:

[Querying Relations](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations)

> Since all types of Eloquent relationships are defined via methods, you may call those methods to obtain an instance of the relationship without actually executing the relationship queries. In addition, all types of Eloquent relationships also serve as query builders, allowing you to continue to chain constraints onto the relationship query before finally executing the SQL against your database.

[Relationship Methods Vs. Dynamic Properties](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#relationship-methods-vs-dynamic-properties)

> If you do not need to add additional constraints to an Eloquent relationship query, you may access the relationship as if it were a property.

Example solution:

```php
return User::find(2)
    ->books()
    ->where([['pages', '>', 100], ['chapters', '>', 3]])
    ->get();
```

Note that we're using `books()` to access the `HasMany` relationship, and using the `where()` query builder method on it to create a constraint. Then, in order to complete and execute the query, we call `get()` at the end. If you don't, you'll just return the daisy chained query builder.

Your previous code might not error, because the value returned from `User::find(2)->books` will be a Collection object, which actually has a `where()` method. It just likely didn't have any matches because of the array format you passed.

Answer (score 0):

To add where clouses on related models, we can use `whereHas()` function.

Since you want **Books**, Start from `Book` model.

```php
$books = Book::where([
    ['pages', '>', 100],
    ['chapters', '>', 3],
])
->whereHas('user', function($query) {
    $query->where('id', 2);
})
->get();
```